# How to get DistributedFileSystem?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am following some example to try to get the DistributedFileSystem using the following, however I found the following returns deprecated error

```
FileSystem fs=FileSystem.get(conf);
DistributedFileSystem hdfs = (DistributedFileSystem) fs;
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem  at
>   Hadoop.File.infoNode(File.java:55)    at
>   Hadoop.Driver.main(Driver.java:8)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a depreciation error

> LocalFileSystem cannot be cast

Your `conf` object needs to be initialized with a `fs.defaultFS` that starts with `hdfs://` instead of `file://`

Check out the core-site.xml file in your `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` to set the property